# The conditional probability and the expected value for a sequence of independent variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expected-value

$X_1, X_2, \dots $ is sequences of independent random variables with a value in $\{ 0,1\}$ s.t $p(X_i=1)=p,~~ \text{for}~~ i \geq 1 $ where $p \in (0,1)$. Assume now we have another sequence $(Y_i )_{i \geq 1}$ of independent random variables with a value in $\{ 0,1\}$ such that $ p (Y_i = 1) = q~$ and also  $ q  \in (0, 1).$

Knowing that $U_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, $V_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i$ and $N = \inf\{n \geq 0, V_{n+1} = 1\}$, I would like to find $E(U_n)$ and the probability $p(U_n = i / N=n )$.

I just see let and assume, I don't know from where to start so any kind of help would be appreciated.

From the comments below, $U_n$ distirbute Binomial $B(n,p)$, the same distribution for $V_n$ as $B(n,pq)$ and $N$ distributes geometric$(pq)$.

How could I use all of this to find the conditional probability?

\begin{eqnarray}
p(U_n = i / N=n ) &=& \frac{p(U_n = i, N=n)}{p(N=n)} ~~\text{but}~~p(U_n = i, N=n)=unknown \nonumber \\
&=& \frac{p(N=n/ U_n = i)p(U_n=i)}{p(N=n)}~~ \text{how to find}~~ p(N=n/ U_n = i)p(U_n=i)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Is your question asking directly to find the expected value and probability or there are other requirements before them? If so, it would be better to write them down maybe they will give a hint to solve or to conclude your questions

Comment: The random variables $X_i$ are Bernoulli , and hence $U$ is a binomial random variable, with parameters $(n, p)$. This should be enough to calculate the expected value

Comment: The $Y_i$ don't seem to have anything to do with the questions you ask.

Comment: @saulspatz in the "stopping time " the stopping condition involves the $Y_i$, am I wrong?

Comment: @RScrlli No, I am wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: @RScrlli Yes this is true and N follows the distribution geometric(pq) but how to calculate the probability

Comment: Shouldn't the stopping condition actually be $V_{n+1}\geq 1$?

Comment: @RScrlli no it is $V_{n+1} = 1$

Comment: Also, the probability is $p(U_n=\color{red}{i}|\cdots)$, where $i$ is some integer?

Comment: @RScrlli I don't have any information about $i$ in the question. It is just asking  to find $p(U_n=i / N=n)$

Answer (score 2):

Since $X_i$'s independent Bernoulli with parameter $p$, $U_i\sim Binom(i,p)$, hence $\mathbb E[U_i] = ip$. 
Concerning $N$ we have
$$ P(N=n) = P(V_1=0,\ldots,V_n =0, V_{n+1} = 1) = P\bigg(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (\{X_i = 0\}\cup \{Y_i = 0\}) \cap \{X_{n+1}=1, Y_{n+1}=1\} \bigg) = (1-pq)^n (pq) $$
Considering the event $\{U_n=i,N=n\}$:
the favorable outcomes are $ ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n), (x_{n+1},y_{n+1}))$ s.t. $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = i$ and $ \prod_{j=1}^n x_jy_j = 0$ and $y_{n+1}=1=x_{n+1}$. The probability of such a fixed outcome is $p^j(1-q)^{i} (1-p)^{n-i} pq$, since there need to be $i$ indices with $x_j=1$ and the corresponding $y_j$'s have to be zero, the remaining $n-i$ (not counting the very last one, where $x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}=1$) pairs can be anything but $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$. The number of such outcomes is $ \binom{n}i $, since there is $\binom{n}i$ ways to chose those $i$ indices with $x_j=1$ and $y_j=0$. So
$$ P\bigg( U_n = i, N=n \bigg) = \binom{n}i p^i(1-q)^i (1-p)^{n-i}pq $$
Update: this means that 
$$U_n | N=n \sim Binom\bigg(n, \frac{p(1-q)}{1-pq}\bigg)$$